# IPV6 and MAC Addresses

Tags: security, tcp, ipv6

I have been studying the new IPV6 addressing system and I have one question that I feel was not answered anywhere in the IPV6 specification, which I have read extensively.  Can a specific IPV6 address be trusted to tie back to a specific unique Device Packet, at a forensic quality level?  I understand that the MAC address of the originating Device is included in the IPV6 and it remains with the message at all stages in its existence.  Packets are never broken up anywhere in its travel and hence one would assume that any 'packet capture' software could, in essence, have the Unique MAC address and could be tracked to one Device and one only.  Is this true or not?

Comment: OSI has nothing to do with TCP/IP. I don't know why they are still teaching it.

Answer (score 2):

Not an invalid question, at one time this is how IPv6 link addresses were generated in practice. But no longer.
It'd require some forensic investigation to determine whether a specific implementation was using this method, but it's unlikely nowdays.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

"The lower 64 bits of the link-local address (the suffix) were originally derived from the MAC address of the underlying network interface card. As this method of assigning addresses would cause undesirable address changes when faulty network cards were replaced, and as it also suffered from a number of security and privacy issues, RFC 8064 has replaced the original MAC-based method with the hash-based method specified in RFC 7217."

Comment: Thanks.  These things have deep evolutionary roots.

Comment: Not all data-link protocols, use MAC addressing, yet they can still carry IPv6 and use the original SLAAC. _[RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html)_ and its predecessors _[RFC 3513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513.html)_ and _[RFC 2373](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2373.html)_, all explain in Appendix A how to create SLAAC addresses for other types of data-link protocols, and IPv6 never required MAC addressing. Please refer to the standards that define IPv6, not something like Wikipedia.

Comment: Nowhere did I or anyone claim MAC addresses were required by IPV6. Nonetheless the following RFCs, now outdated, all plainly specify the use of MAC addresses in generating an IPV6 address, so keep trying - 
RFC2464, RFC2467, RFC2492, RFC2470, RFC3572, RFC4291

Comment: And nothing you have said even contradicts what wikpedia said, wikipedia also directly references the RFCs...

Comment: "_The lower 64 bits of the link-local address (the suffix) were originally derived from the MAC address of the underlying network interface card._" Quoting something so completely incorrect does not make it so. All the way back to [RFC 2373](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2373) that described generating SLAAC, that was only one of the methods for generating an IID. "_The only requirement is that it be unique on the link. There are many possible approaches to select a link-unique interface identifier._" Wikipedia is not the source to use for this.

Comment: To say that something is or has been done a certain way in practice is not to say that it must be done that way. Once again, nowhere did I or anyone claim MAC addresses were required by IPV6. The wiki quote there does not imply that. You keep framing the conversation this way, I've told you this repeatedly... I've just linked you multiple RFCs that describe the use of MAC in generating IPv6 addresses

Comment: I think this should be marked as a right answer. It addresses both the main question and the concern behind it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been studying the new IPV6 addressing system...

IPv6 is hardly new; it dates back to 1995, when *[RFC 1883, Internet Protocol, Version 6 (IPv6) Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1883)* was published.

> Can a specific IPV6 address be trusted to tie back to a specific
> unique Device Packet, at a forensic quality level?

I'm not completely sure what you mean. IPv6 restores the IP end-to-end paradigm, where every host has a unique IP address, but there are non-standard techniques that can disrupt that.

> I understand that the MAC address of the originating Device is
> included in the IPV6 and it remains with the message at all stages in
> its existence.

I'm not sure where you got that idea. IP (both IPv4 and IPv6) have nothing to do with the data-link protocol used to carry them. IP can be carried by any number of data-link protocols, and only the IEEE protocols (ethernet, Wi-Fi, token ring, etc.) use MAC addressing. Other data link protocols (frame relay, PPP, ATM, HDLC, etc.), including common residential WAN protocols (PPPoA) do not use MAC addressing. The data-link addressing is only valid on the data-link LAN.

> Packets are never broken up anywhere in its travel and hence one would
> assume that any 'packet capture' software could, in essence, have the
> Unique MAC address and could be tracked to one Device and one only. Is
> this true or not?

MAC addresses are data-link addresses, and they are not valid or seen beyond the local LAN.

Comment: I understand that the MAC address of the originating Device is included in the IPV6 and it remains with the message at all stages in its existence.  Should have read 'I understand that the MAC address of the originating Device is included in the IPV6 header (second 64 bits) and it remains with the message at all stages in its existence.

Comment: I think you are confusing something. The original SLAAC could use a MAC address (if one exists for an interface) or other host identifier to build the IID for IPv6 addresses associated with the interface, but that is not a requirement, and, in fact, most OSes use random IIDs. Also, as I pointed out, not all interfaces use protocols that even have MAC addresses. MAC, and other data-link, addresses are only on the frame that gets destroyed as a packet passes through a router.

Comment: @robertdaleweir, besides SLAAC, with our without random IIDs, you can use manual address configuration or DHCPv6.

Comment: So in essence there is no verifiable way to detect the source of any communication back to any specific Device and/or Geo-location, period!

Comment: Not really any more or less than for IPv4. Geo-location doesn't really work, anyway. Sometimes it works to get you close, but if you were to try to use it on my address, it would give you the location of my ISP headquarters, over 1000 miles away, and addresses can move physical location all the time, and anycast means the same address can simultaneously be in various places all over the world (think about Google `8.8.8.8`).

Comment: I believe I now understand a bit more about this area thanks to your answers. Have a great day...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6
"The lower 64 bits of the link-local address (the suffix) were originally derived from the MAC address of the underlying network interface card. As this method of assigning addresses would cause undesirable address changes when faulty network cards were replaced, and as it also suffered from a number of security and privacy issues, RFC 8064 has replaced the original MAC-based method with the hash-based method specified in RFC 7217."

Comment: "_The lower 64 bits of the link-local address (the suffix) were originally derived from the MAC address of the underlying network interface card._" Not necessarily. Not all data-link protocols use MAC addressing, and the RFC explains that any relatively unique number on a host could be used. Some protocols use 64-bit MAC addresses, and you could simply set the U.L bit and use it directly. Protocols using 48-bit MAC addresses use the method for creating a modified eui-64, and there are suggestions for other numbers.

Comment: Sure but I fail to see how this is consistent with your statement here: 

"I understand that the MAC address of the originating Device is included in the IPV6 and it remains with the message at all stages in its existence"

"I'm not sure where you got that idea. IP (both IPv4 and IPv6) have nothing to do with the data-link protocol used to carry them. ... "

Comment: @ibrust, I did not say that, that was the OP. I pointed out that IPv6 addressing does not require the use of a MAC address.

Comment: "Does not require" and "has nothing to do with" are quite different, keep trying.

Comment: @ibrust, I do not get your point. It is true that IPv4 and IPv6 have nothing to do with the data-link protocol, although one is required. They can both be carried by any data-link protocol (PPP, frame relay, ethernet, ATM, HDLC, Wi-Fi, token ring, FDDI, ARCNET, etc.), and neither knows or cares which is used. Also, the data-link protocols (other than PPP, which has the NCP component) does not know or care which network protocol (IPv4, IPX, AppleTalk, IPv6, etc.) it is carrying. That is the beauty of the network layers that you can mix and match the protocols.